# Concatenate hyperlink in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am trying to concatenate a URL with many different parts(variables) added to the end of the URL.

I have a button and when you click the button it will takes you to the a specific site using the slide index of the current slide.

When the button is click I want it to go to **"google.com/p" + Slide.Index + slide.ID + ActivePresentation.fileName**

I know the syntax aren't correct but hopefully you get the GIST.

Currently I have this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim projId AS Integer = 617
    Dim URL AS String = "www.google.com"
    Dim coID = "m01"
    Dim coTitle AS String = "New CC Project"
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim pgId



    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:="http://google.com/p" + oSl.SlideID
    NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you a bit closer:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    ' You can't assign values to variables at the same time
    ' as you DIM them; you CAN do so with Constants:
    Const projId As Integer = 617
    Const URL As String = "www.google.com"
    Const coID As String = "m01"
    Const coTitle As String = "New CC Project"
    Dim oSl As Slide
    'Dim pgId

    ' You can't just refer to oSl; you have to first tell it WHICH slide
    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) ' or whatever slide you want

    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:="http://google.com/p" & oSl.SlideID, _
    NewWindow:=True, _
    AddHistory:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is always evaluated in a string context, while `+` may not concatenate if one of the operands is no string:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim projId AS Integer
    Dim URL AS String = "www.google.com"
    Dim coID = "m01"
    Dim coTitle AS String = "New CC Project"
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim pgId
    projId = 617


    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
    Address="http://google.com/p" & oSl.SlideID
    NewWindow=True
    AddHistory=True


End Sub
```

Comment: Why am I getting an error on `Dim projId AS Integer = 617` and `NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, view the code below!

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim sl As slide
    Dim projId As Integer
    Dim coID As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim coTitle As String
    Dim pgId
    URL = "www.google.com"
    projId = 617
    coID = "m01"
    coTitle = "New CC Project"

    Set sl = SlideShowWindows(1).View.slide

    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:=URL & projId & "&coIdent=" & coID & "&coTitle=" & coTitle & "&pgIdent=" & sl.slideId & "&pgTitle=" & sl.slideId & "&pageFileName=" & ActivePresentation.FullName & "&pageOrder=" & sl.SlideIndex, _
    NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True
```